# Can I use SPACE as mapleader in VIM?

Tags: vim, configuration, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

From [http://items.sjbach.com/319/configuring-vim-right (2009 archive from original)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090213130939/http://items.sjbach.com/319/configuring-vim-right) I got that you were supposed to be able to use <kbd>Space</kbd> as the `mapleader` in vim. I've tried but it does not seem to work. Is there anyone who made it work?

Tried:

```
let mapleader = <space>
```

Comment: Awesome! Just read the same blog post and found this after trying <SPACE> ... I found that in MacVim this didn't remove the mapping of "move one character forward" from the spacebar, so for others who find this from Google - add "nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop>" before the "let mapleader..." this worked for me.

Comment: I use `let mapleader = " "`. You can also try let mapleader = "\<Space>".

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
let mapleader=" "
```

And remember to write the following line before that, to make sure spacebar doesn't have any mapping beforehand:

```
nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop>
```

Comment: As spacemanaki comments in the question above `nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop>` was needed to get this working.

Comment: @Sasha : really ? Could you explain why, and if it really is, then maybe you should edit the question.

Comment: Without sasha's mapping, pressing <Space> will not behave like other keys as mapleader. <Space> in normal mode is mapped to <right>. Just press <space> a couple of times in a row and you will see undesired behaviour, which can be fixed by `nnoremap <Space> <nop>`.

Comment: To add to this answer, note that the value of `mapleader` takes only affect mappings which happen after `mapleader` is set. See `:help leader`.

Comment: I had to save and close the rc file. I was using `:source %` but the space remap was not working.

Answer (score 82):

Mapleader is a Vim string variable. To use space as leader, you must escape the special character.

```
let mapleader="\<Space>"
```

For more info see,

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-quote

**EDIT:**

This no longer works for me in my version of Vim. Even with the suggestion in the comments of unmapping the spacebar in normal mode by running `nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop>`.

I ending up going with the solution given in the answer below.

```
map <Space> <Leader>
```

Comment: Also, make sure you use double quotes `"\<Space>"` and not `'\<Space>'`.

Comment: I prefer this answer.

Comment: `let mapleader = "\<Space>"` worked for me in nvim, but not in vim. `map <Space> <Leader>` also does not work in vim for me.

Comment: `noremap <Space> <Nop>` `map <Space> <Leader>` worked in vim

Comment: I had to remove the space around `=` for mine to work, on Neovim.

Comment: *"my version of Vim"* - could you say which version?

Answer (score 22):

The above solutions are great, however, nothing shows up in the bottom right command corner. If you don't have any use for the `\` key anyway, try using
`map <SPACE> <leader>` and `\` will show up in the command corner. That and you don't have to unmap space first, as suggested in the commends above.

Comment: This breaks The NERD Commenter. And at least in Vim 8 and Neovim space shows up as `<20>` if `showcmd` is on, so I guess with new enough Vim this answer is obsolete.

Comment: I just want to add here that this is also the best solution if you have already developed muscle memory for the default leader, but want to start using space instead for better efficiency.  "\r" is still wired into my muscle memory for opening Nerd Tree and using cscope, so it is nice that it still works even when mapping space to leader (I don't feel a need to use Nerd Commenter, though).

Comment: wow! I've been using `,` as leader had no idea that `\ ` would show up in the bottom corner... hmm, I guess `,` does show up too, but never really noticed it before.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using neovim and lua config, you can try it:

```
-- map leader to <Space>
vim.keymap.set("n", " ", "<Nop>", { silent = true, remap = false })
vim.g.mapleader = " "
```

Answer (score 0):

nnoremap <space> <Nop>
nnoremap <nowait> <space> /