# How do I set a special char as a mapleader in Vim?

Tags: vim

### Failed attempts

**With quotes**

`let mapleader = "<Delete>"`

**Without quotes**

`let mapleader = <Delete>`

> E15: Invalid expression: `<Delete>`

**Other keys**

`let mapleader = "<Escape>"`

`let mapleader = "<Insert>"`

---

## Baseline

Using a comma works.

`let mapleader = ","`

---

### What I'm really trying to do

I'm trying to set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as a mapleader in Vim. Using xmodmap, I can clear <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>'s functionality and assign it to a new key. I'd like to assign it to <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then assign one of those as a mapleader in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

## Use an escape character

`let mapleader = "\<Delete>"`

`let mapleader = "\<Esc>"`

`let mapleader = "\<Insert>"`

---

More info: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-quote

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578616/3822261