# Map <space> to <leader> in VIM

Tags: vim

I want to map the `<space>` key to `<leader>` (which is currently the `\` key here) in VIM 7.4.

I would also like to be able to use both the `<space>` and `\` keys as leaders.

If possible, it would be great to see the `/` character appearing in the bottom right corner when I type it (instead of funky stuff like `<20>`), but I can live without it.

I've tried to

```
nmap <space> <bslash>
```

this works for simple `<leader>keys` commands, but `<leader><leader>key` commands (like the *easymotion* maps) don't work.

I also tried to

```
let mapleader = " "
nmap <bslash> <space>
```

but analogously to the problem above stated, the `<bslash>` key doesn't work anymore for `<leader><leader>key` commands.

I already tried a bunch of stuff in these related questions/wiki pages:

- [Can I use SPACE as mapleader in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446269/can-i-use-space-as-mapleader-in-vim)
- [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_2)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2))
- `:h mapleader`

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your `.vimrc`, so I can't guarantee this is the issue, but I would bet that the issue comes from using `nnoremap`. The following works for me:

```
let mapleader =" "
nmap <leader>i iHello World<esc>
nmap <bslash> <space>
```

I can use either `<space>i` or `<bslash>i` and both of them run the `iHello World<esc>` mapping. But this:

```
let mapleader =" "
nnoremap <leader>i iHello World<esc>
nnoremap <bslash> <space>
```

Does not work. `<space>i` runs the mapping, but `<bslash>i` does not, which is exactly what should be expected, since `nnoremap` is used to avoid nested/recursive mappings. So one possible solution would be to use `nmap` everywhere. I would definitely not recommend this, since you'll likely end up in a map loop. This solution should work better:

```
let mapleader =" "
nnoremap <leader>i iHello World<esc>
nmap <expr> <bslash> mapleader
```

Note that if you change the mapleader setting, this will break because, as `:h mapleader` says:

```
Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
mappings.
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am indeed using nmap. Using `nmap <space> <bslash>`  it works for single `<leader>` commands, but not for `<leader><leader>` commands. I really don't know why.

Comment: `<leader><leader>` problem can be solved with the single [`let g:mapleader = "\<Space>"`](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/hy3yma/comment/fzajann/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and `nnoremap <leader><leader> itest` which will input `test` from the normal mode in vim9 now. It seems not one good habit to use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` to avoid recursive definition problem.